# Scalable, regional and Rails happy approaches to RESTful routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, restful-authentication

What's the Rails-ey & RESTful way to route an app that will reference entities on a national (global?) scale? *Edit: this is not related to internationalization (i18n)*

users should be able to browse & bookmark entities and optionally log in. each entity will have user(s) *(admins?)* that can log in and CRUD entities they're associated with. and of course, super-admins can CRUD everything.

i can think of:

```
/entity/id  #too simple
/us/ma/marblehead/<entity-name>
/entity-name-plus-unique-region-name
```

what happens if your an admin?

i know this is relatively basic stuff but I'm still trying to wrap my head around routes and the best ways to set up `routes.rb`.

Comment: I didn't think this question would be a stumper?!?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to internationalization? If so, the Rails Guides has some great walkthroughs with very solid suggestions on how to handle this stuff:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale

Comment: thanks but at first glance that link seems to be talking about **i18n** which i'm not really talking about...nor am i interested in **g11n**. both assume the app needs to *change* somehow when viewed by a user w/in said locale. i'm simply talking about how to 'organize' my resources under a routing scheme... maybe we should bring this down to a regional discussion. think states/provinces, counties, and cities.

Comment: Gotcha. You should clarify in your question. You can probably infer some great practices with routing from that document still. You should also look at namespaces in the routing guide. They are probably a worthy resource.